# Error on importing VueAnalytics to main.ts in Vue CLI (Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, vuejs3

The following error message is given:

"Argument of type 'typeof VueAnalytics' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin_2'.
Type 'typeof VueAnalytics' is not assignable to type '{ install: PluginInstallFunction; }'.
Types of property 'install' are incompatible."

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you very much for your help.

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import VueAnalytics from "vue-analytics";

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(VueAnalytics, {id:'', router})
  .mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that the plugin was built for Vue 2 and is not compatible with Vue 3.  Checking the package's [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-analytics) reveals that there have been no updates in the last year.  The requirement also lists Vue 2.

The last [Github](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-analytics) commit was in January.

Following some links from the package's Github leads to [this package](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag-next) which looks like it may work with Vue 3.